# MySQL Under High Load, Race Condition?

Tags: mysql

I am experiencing what appears to be the effects of a race condition in an application I am involved with. The situation is as follows, generally, a page responsible for some heavy application logic is following this format:

Select from `test` and determine if there are rows already matching a clause.
If a matching row already exists, we terminate here, otherwise we proceed with the application logic
Insert into the `test` table with values that will match our initial select.

Normally, this works fine and limits the action to a single execution. However, under high load and user-abuse where many requests are intentionally sent simultaneously, MySQL allows many instances of the application logic to run, bypassing the restriction from the select clause.

It seems to actually run something like:
select from test
select from test
select from test
(all of which pass the check)
insert into test
insert into test
insert into test

I believe this is done for efficiency reasons, but it has serious ramifications in the context of my application. I have attempted to use Get_Lock() and Release_Lock() but this does not appear to suffice under high load as the race condition still appears to be present. Transactions are also not a possibility as the application logic is very heavy and all tables involved are not transaction-capable.

To anyone familiar with this behavior, is it possible to turn this type of handling off so that MySQL always processes queries in the order in which they are received? Is there another way to make such queries atomic? Any help with this matter would be appreciated, I can't find much documented about this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you have, as you surmised, a race condition.

The `SELECT` and the `INSERT` need to be one *atomic* unit.

The way you do this is via *transactions*. You cannot safely make the `SELECT`, return to PHP, and assume the `SELECT`'s results will reflect the database state when you make the `INSERT`.

If well-designed transactions (the correct solution) are as you say not possible - and I still strongly recommend them - you're going to have to make the final `INSERT` **atomically** check if its assumptions are still true (such as via an `INSERT IF NOT EXISTS`, a stored procedure, or catching the `INSERT`'s error in the application). If they aren't, it will abort back to your PHP code, which must start the logic over.

By the way, MySQL likely *is* executing requests in the order they were received. It's possible with multiple simultaneous connections to receive `SELECT A`,`SELECT B`,`INSERT A`,`INSERT B`. Thus, the only "solution" would be to only allow one connection at a time - and that will kill your scalability dead.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a possible solution. How would one go about atomically checking if the assumptions are still true. If via a simple select as done at the top of the logic, is it not possible the new data will still not yet be reflected in the table?

Comment: @majicbunnie You make the second `INSERT` a stored procedure which does `BEGIN TRANSACTION; SELECT; [check]; INSERT; END TRANSACTION;`.

Comment: Thank you, I think this will work for me, although I may need to change some storage engine types to support transactions. As i understand it they must all be transaction-capable for a solution like this to function.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would go about the check another way.

Attempt to insert the row. If it fails, then there was already a row there.

In this manner, you check or a duplicate and insert the new row in a single query, eliminating the possibility of races.